# GraphQL only select items of certain type from array

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo, graphql-js

In my GraphQL API I have defined a `course` fragment with an array property `lessons`.

Initially it only had lessons of type `TextLesson`. Later we added lessons of type `VideoLesson` as well.

```
fragment TextLessonFields on TextLesson {
  title
  body
}

#fragment VideoLessonFields on VideoLesson {
#  title
#  videoUrl
#}


fragment CourseFields on Course {
  lessons {
    ... on TextLesson {
      ...TextLessonFields
    }
    #... on VideoLesson { # not present on older app versions, but data in backend db has videos now
    #  ...VideoLessonFields
    #}
   }
}

query GetCourse {
  Course(id: "fake-course-id") {
    ...CourseFields
  }
}
```

Unfortunately now when older clients fetch the course the lessons property ends up with empty objects in the response like this:

```
{
  data: {
    Course: {
      lessons: [
        {
          __typename: "TextLesson"
          title: "text lesson",
          body: "Lorem ipsum",
        },
        {} # Video lesson ends up being downloaded as empty object. Could it just somehow not add this empty object in the response?
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Is there anyway to completely ignore the objects of different type in the lessons array and only fetch the ones known to the client at the time?

We are using React Native with Apollo client currently:

```
"@apollo/client": "3.8.6",
"graphql": "16.8.1",
```

Our client initialisation code:

```
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client";

import Config from "services/config";

export const sanityApolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  uri: Config.GRAPHQL_URL,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${Config.GRAPHQL_API_TOKEN}`,
  },
  defaultOptions: {
    watchQuery: {
      // First use cache, but also fetch new content from network.
      fetchPolicy: "cache-and-network",
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Is the client version passed to the server somehow? If so you can add it to the `context` and then modify your resolver to return different results depending on that version.

Comment: The server is actually Sanity Data lake so not sure if we have much control on that side

Comment: If you can't modify the resolvers on the server and you can't modify the already deployed clients then you are kind of stuck afaict. The GraphQL language doesn't have conditionals.